# i am writing the helper class and i am getting the error in the helper function itself '=>' expected ts(1005)[Ln2 Col57] What the correct way to write

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-apps, helper

```
({
    getAccountsHelper:(component,event,helper){
      let action=component.get("c.getAccounts()");
      action.setStorable();
      action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        if(response.getState()=='SUCCESS')
        {
            let accountData=response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.accounts",accountData);
      
        }
        else if(state==="ERROR"){
            let errors=response.getError();
            console.error('errors',JSON.stringify(errors));
            if(errors){
                if(errors[0] && errors[0].message)
                {
                   var toastEvent=$A.get('e.force.showToast');
                   toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title":"Error!",
                     "message":errors[0].message,
                     "type":"error"
                   })
                   toastEvent.fire();
                }
            }
         }
         component.set("v.loadSpinner",false);
      });
      //enequeue the server side action
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not clear, but I can see a syntax error on the 2nd line.

```
let action=component.get("c.getAccounts()");
```

To call a server side action, you don't need to add the brackets.

correct syntax : `let action=component.get("c.getAccounts");`

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm